# Web app ClaimsIdentity in Webapi

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I've created a mvc web application that uses openid to authenticate with Azure Ad and get the claims along with the token. I'm interfacing with Web Api to do the business transactions. The web Api is configured to oauth bearer tokens.

I've created separate oauth clients in Azure Ad for the Web App and Web Api. I'm able to get a token for Web Api from the Mvc Controller using AuthenticationContext to send to request to Web Api. I need to know how I can send the current User Claims as well to the Web Api. The claims in the Web Api are not having the claims of the User from the Web App.

Let me provide a bit more context here. I've created a MVC Web Application and a Web Api layer. The MVC Web App is configured to use OpenID authentication using Azure AD and I've configured the Web Api layer to authorize using OAuth Bearer tokens. The actions in the Web Api layer will be called through ajax requests and the bearer token will be added to the header of each Ajax requests. When the User is authenticated in the Web App, additional claims are added to the User on top of the claims from Azure Ad. I'm able to create a token for the Web Api layer using AuthenticationContext.AcquireToken, but the token for Web Api does not have the User info from the Web App.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actully I didn't make much headway. The UserAssertion expects a token belonging to the Web Api and I cant get the User password to create a UserCredential object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a wild stab in the dark here, based on what I think is happening.

Claims are attached the user, so theoretically, any claim you add in one place should be available in the other, as long as both applications share the same user datastore. However, claims are loaded at the point of authentication and not dynamically updated. As a result, if you're already logged in to the web application and you add a claim with your Web Api, that claim will not be available on the web application side until the user is re-authenticated.

Comment: Hi, that does provide some context. Thanks. Just a general clarification, how can I associate a token, obtained for a web Api authorization with a User. Apparently the token I received from Azure Ad for the Web Api is not associated with any user id.